# The correct way to permanently set properties on a ServicePoint

Tags: c#, servicepoint, servicepointmanager

I would like to turn off Nagle algorithm on a specific connection (in my case - to an ElasticSearch server).

My code currently looks something like this:

```
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(uriWithoutLocalPath)).UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```

The problem is that the `ServicePoint` object is being recycled after a while, which causes it to lose the setting. Therefore, I can't just run this code once, at system startup. It would seem I have several options in front of me:

1. Globally turn off Nagle algorithm (hence, affecting connections I don't want to affect).
2. Increase [MaxServicePointIdleTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepointidletime(v=vs.110).aspx), so that the `ServicePoint` is never recycled (probably a bad idea? My intuition tells me so).
3. Set some sort of timer that resets the properties every N seconds where N is smaller than the recycling time for a `ServicePoint`.
4. Reset the properties every time I use the connection.

I don't really like any of these options, they either affect other things in the system, or seem too complex for what I want to do (like the timer option). It seems to me that there should be a simple solution to this. Ideas?

Comment: Hmm, seems like you've listed the viable options.  I would go with #4, reset properties when you create the connection.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: I would have to do that every time I use the connection, not create it. I am worried about performance and thread safety if I go this route, FindServicePoint doesn't look like the kind of method I want to call 100 times per second

Comment: @DoronYaacoby did you find any alternatives? I am facing the same problem and currently employ solution #4, but share your concerns regarding performance.

Comment: @enzi sadly, no. I went for solution number 1 and it didn't seem to cause performance problems with other connections, so I stayed with that.